# Hibernate Creates new Entity Unnecessarily When Running on a Different Thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA, running the following test results in counter-intuitive behavior

```
@Test
public void testAsync() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Job job = jobRepository.save(new Job());
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    long origJobID = job.getId();
    executor.initialize();
    Future<?> wait = executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Job outcome = jobRepository.save(job.setStopTime(Instant.now()));
        // this assertion fails, Hibernate requested a new ID and persisted a new entity ... even though I am reusing the same instance with an ID already populated
        assertEquals(origJobID, outcome.getId().longValue());
    });
    wait.get();
}
```

Since `jobRepository` only provide a `save()` interface, as a user I of the service I can only call this method to INSERT or UPDATE my entity ... how is it possible that the underlying entity manager just ignore the fact that my entity already has an ID and goes ahead and creates a duplicate row?

Looking further into Hibernate's codebase, it appears on a new Thread, the persistentContext is wiped clean. Therefore my entity is turned into a DETACHED state as far as the `DefaultMergeEventListener` is concerned ... creating a cascade of decisions that inexplicably leading to the generation of a new ID

The specific code I reference is located at: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultMergeEventListener.java#L109

If run from a new Thread, Hibernate's persistence context is empty ... which is fine .... but then I don't understand why is my entity now considered **DETACHED** ...

More excerpt from Hibernate's source code: Default
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultMergeEventListener.java#L293

```
if ( result == null ) {
            //TODO: we should throw an exception if we really *know* for sure
            //      that this is a detached instance, rather than just assuming
            //throw new StaleObjectStateException(entityName, id);

            // we got here because we assumed that an instance
            // with an assigned id was detached, when it was
            // really persistent
            entityIsTransient( event, copyCache );
        }
```

**EDIT** If this is related to the fact that the transactions are not committed yet, and the new thread does not use the same transaction ... is there a way to force a transaction in code?

Note calling `JpaRepository.saveAndFlush()` does not resolve the issue

**EDIT 2** I am using embedded h2 for this test, in either case, I expected `saveAndFlush()` to have committed the transaction to the database (embedded or on the other side of the world) so that multiple threads can use the JpaRepository to view the states saved by the other Threads right?

**EDIT 3** Looking at other similar questions, it appears marking the test method itself as **@Transaction(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED)** forces the underlying transaction manager to commit upon `JpaRepository.save()` ... this is still confusing ... how was the test method transactional to begin with? i.e. why did the transaction not commit to begin with?

Comment: `flush()` in this context means "issue the necessary SQL". It does *not* mean "commit the transaction". Flushing and committing are almost orthogonal issues ("almost" because committing typically implies flushing)

Comment: Got it thats for that explanation. I am still wondering how does Spring when the caller invokes `JpaRepository` methods determine the scope of when transactions are committed ... for my test method, adding propagation not supported apparently causes all `save()` to commit immediate

Comment: transaction = not supported in your case basically means "every SQL is inside a different transaction". To control the scope of your transactions, you can read http://springinpractice.com/2008/03/18/annotation-based-transactions-in-spring or http://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very rough idea of how it works:

- You have multiple threads
- Transactions are typically thread-bound (each thread gets its own transaction)
- `EntityManager`s are typically transaction-bound (each transaction has its own `EntityManager`, which sees things according to that transaction)

What you are doing is

1. Tell the entity manager in thread 1 that you want to make entity A persistent / save its changes (that is what save() means in Spring Data)
2. Pass entity A to thread 2
3. Tell the entity manager in thread 2 that you want to make entity A persistent / save its changes

As the entity managers are in different transactions and thread 1 has not committed its transaction when 3. is executed, from the point of view of thread 2 entity A is not yet persistent; so it will interpret `save()` (or `saveAndFlush()`) as "make entity A persistent" and not as "save changes in entity A". And making entity A persistent implies assigning a new ID to entity A if necessary.

You should be able to make this work by ensuring that thread 1 has already committed when step 3. is executed. Anyway I do not recommend passing managed entity references between threads as it gets tricky really fast.

About Spring Data transaction demarcation, you can read https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions for more information, but it basically involves making each transaction a method and then annotating that method.

Comment: thanks, I will read through those. It is definitely my preference that transaction on each thread commit as a way to communicate persisted state. As It is ok for a race condition to exist on the timing of such commits across different threads in my case (and many other cases) as the failed transaction will just have to roll back